# java - creating empty GZIP file

Tags: java, zip, gzip

i am trying to solve a simple problem - creating an empty GZip file using Java, so that no excpetion is raised when trying to read from it. if I do:

```
Files.createFile(outPutFile);
new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPutFile.toFile())), true).close();
```

It solves the problem - i guess the GZipOutputStream stores some furthr data in the file. is there a more succinct way to achieve the above i.e. not getting Unexpected end of Zlib archive exception?

Comment: What is the reading code you want to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't need to call `createFile` to start with - creating a `FileOutputStream` will do that. And you don't need the `PrintWriter` either. So all you need is:

```
new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPutFile)).close();
```

It's odd to capitalize the `P` in `outPutFile` by the way - it's not like it's three words...

Comment: Hmm, I thought it worked but it is still throwing exception. After i create a file it has 20 bytes and an empty file within the archive. Howver, if i try to open it using `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))));` it fails

Comment: OK, the exception is thrown whenever I try to readLine() from the file

Comment: @Bober02: *What* exception is thrown? I'm not sure what you mean by "an empty file within the archive" - GZIP isn't like a zip file; it doesn't have multiple files. It's just a compressed stream.

Comment: OK: The output is a compressed empty stream. Whenver I wrap the GzipInputStream in a BufferedReader and try to readLine() I get EOFException:  Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream